# UIDragInteraction / UIDropItem get frame of preview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Currently I’m trying to get the frame of my drag/drop interaction object preview view. I can get the position of my finger thanks to:

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view;
```

I’ve searched through everything and can’t find a way to access the preview view object, or a frame reference. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out - I found out there's a method called after the actual drop function that provides a `UITargetedDragPreview` object. So my logic is to store the drop session and interaction, then call my "update" function when this preview function has been called.

First, I create some variables for future use:

```
CGRect destinationFrame;                //  destination frame.
UIDropInteraction *storedInteraction;   //  stored interaction.
id <UIDropSession> storedSession;       //  stored session.
```

```
- (UITargetedDragPreview *)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction previewForDroppingItem:(UIDragItem *)item withDefault:(UITargetedDragPreview *)defaultPreview {

   if (!item.localObject) { return nil; }

    CGPoint center = defaultPreview.target.center;
    CGPoint converted = [defaultPreview.target.container convertPoint:center toView:<TARGETVIEW>];
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(converted.x - (defaultPreview.view.frame.size.width / 2), converted.y - (defaultPreview.view.frame.size.height / 2));

    self->destinationFrame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, defaultPreview.view.frame.size.width, defaultPreview.view.frame.size.height);

    if (self->storedSession && self->storedInteraction) {
        [self performDropWithInteraction:self->storedInteraction session:self->storedSession];
    }

    return nil;

}

- (void)dropInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction performDrop:(id<UIDropSession>)session {
    self->storedInteraction = interaction;
    self->storedSession = session;
}

- (void)performDropWithInteraction:(UIDropInteraction *)interaction session:(id<UIDropSession>)session {
   //  this where I will perform my actual drop, I get the frame with:
   //  self->destinationFrame.
}
```